# g++ error in vscode: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, g++

In VSCode whenever I try to compile a cpp file I get the following error:

```
> Executing task: 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe' -g d:\helloworld\helloworld.cpp -o d:\helloworld\helloworld.exe <

g++.exe: error: d:helloworldhelloworld.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

This is how the `tasks.json` file looks like:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? Of [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) ? Did you try to run your `g++` command in a terminal? Pay attention to your [working current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) ... Consider perhaps installing a Linux distribution (e.g. [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) ...) on your laptop.

Comment: I checked the VSCode tutorial but that didn't help. And about installing ubuntu, I don't think this is a windows related issue

Comment: But did you read the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc) ? What will happen to you if you spend several hours in reading that documentation? [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) also has some documentation....

Comment: Did you try using forward slashes, e.g. replace `d:\helloworld\helloworld.cpp` with `d:/helloworld/helloworld.cpp` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks a lot. Reading the GCC docs really helped.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know this is not the right place to talk about this but I am a CPP beginner so can you suggest some good resources to learn CPP for real-world applications instead of being stuck in the tutorials phase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232380/discussion-between-prabodh-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Basile Starynkevitch, reading the documentation helped. This seems to work fine:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "CPP - BUILD FILE",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe ${relativeFile}",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using `g++ -Wall -Wextra` instead of just  `g++`. And you probably want debugging info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok I'll add those

Comment: I suggest `-O3 -pedantic -pedantic-errors` too. For debug builds: `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined` is really helpful.

Comment: @TedLyngmo an upvote maybe ??? LOL just kidding but if you think the answer would be helpful to others then please consider giving me an upvote